# Strange LINQ query error

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, exception

I am trying to databind this query.

```
 cboTypeStage.DataSource = 
        (
            from ts in tsRepository.GetTable()
            select new { IdTypeStage = Convert.ToDecimal(-1), Description = "Aucun", NomFormEval = "-" }
        )
        .Union
        (
            from ts in tsRepository.GetTable()
            join o in oRepository.GetTable() on ts.IdOrthEvalFormulaire equals o.IdOrthEvalFormulaire
            where (ts.IdProgramme == Convert.ToDecimal(Session["selectedProg"]))
            select new { IdTypeStage = ts.IdTypeStage, Description = ts.Description, NomFormEval = ((o.Nom == null) ? "Aucun" : o.Nom) }
        );
```

But i can't seem to get it working. i am getting next error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlNew' to type 'System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlValue'

I want to convert this SQL query to LINQ

```
SELECT -1 AS IdTypeStage, 'Aucun' AS Description, '-' AS NomFormEval
UNION
SELECT ts.IdTypeStage AS IdTypeStage, ts.Description AS Description, ISNULL(eref.Nom, 'Aucun') AS NomFormEval FROM TypeStage AS ts
LEFT OUTER JOIN OrthEvalFormulaire AS eref ON eref.IdOrthEvalFormulaire = ts.IdEvalFormulaire 
WHERE IdProgramme = @IdProgramme
```

Any ideas on the error ?

Thanks.

Comment: do each of the parts of the union query work independently?

Comment: btw, you can use `NomFormEval = o.Nom ?? "Aucun"`

Comment: @JeffN85: they do work independently.

Comment: @abatishchev: Thanks for the tip i didn't know about a null operator like this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use Concat as described in the answers to this question - [Inserting extra data in a linq result but not to the data source or waiting for submiting changes on a context object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300449/inserting-extra-data-in-a-linq-result-but-not-to-the-data-source-or-waiting-for-s)

---

Additionally, please be aware that

```
from ts in tsRepository.GetTable()
        select new { IdTypeStage = Convert.ToDecimal(-1), Description = "Aucun", NomFormEval = "-" }
```

will give you one extra "aucun" row for each and every row in the repository - I'm guessing that this isn't what you wanted.

Comment: Well "aucun" mean None in english. I need to be able to select nothing from the combobox that is why there an union. I will try the concat solution.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to use `Concat()` instead of `Join()`
- Try to create not anonymous types but strongly-typed

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool such as LINQER to convert the SQL to LINQ. Tools are way better at this than we are :-)

See http://www.sqltolinq.com.

Comment: I would like to avoid using trial tools.